# What should I picture when I read 终端？

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a text talking about a GPS system. 北斗卫星 导航 系统

北斗系统终端不仅可以为船只导航，还能通过其特有的短报文通信技术，报告船只位置和随航人员的情况。

Should I just picture a computer terminal when I read 终端? A screen where I can see information and enter commands? Or does 终端 refer to more?

Comment: 终端 does mean "terminal" in computer communication terms

Comment: Normally this would mean an interface for communicate with a computerized system by inputting commands and reading outputs. You need to see the specific use case in order to understand what they're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

“北斗系统終端” should be interpreted as any devices such chart plotter, fish finder, handheld gps, vhf radio with built-in gps, gps watch, epirb with gps, mob device with gps, camera with gps.

the list is much longer, with the satellite sms facilities.

if you think of computer terminal only, it’s, well, you’re landbuddy :)

have a look of marine products associated with gps, you’ll have the idea

https://www.fisheriessupply.com/sitesearch.aspx?keyword=gps&sitesearch=true

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks! All I know about fish is: I like them fried! Just a friendly tip: I would normally refer to a "landlubber" = "A useless long-shorer; a vagrant stroller. Applied by sailors to the mass of landsmen, especially those without employment" But maybe "landbuddy" is American? I don't know.

Comment: for unknown people, it’s ok to use landlubber. well, describe someone as “useless” is, imo, not polite. that’s why the “land” + “buddy” is invented  btw, i like steamed fish 